# Should dimensional analysis problems be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

We've had a few dimensional analysis questions in the past, but we've recently had quite a few more.  I'm not calling anyone out here, I'm just stating a fact.

These homework examples may not involve chemistry directly, but are a stepping stone towards students being able to manage mol ratios, etc.  Many of the questions involve units which may be more reserved for physics, economics, etc.

People have flagged and commented that these problems belong on other sites.  My feeling thus far is that because this concept (for better or worse) is part of the modern chemistry curriculum, it should be on-topic.  I am starting to think I'm outnumbered in this regard, and I'm considering changing this position if that's how the community feels.

Note that these are definitely off-topic for Physics.SE either way, since they don't really accept "non-conceptual" problems.  I suppose Math.SE is a possibility for migrations, but their users might argue these textbook problems are more of a "science" issue.

Should these questions be on-topic on Chemistry.SE?

Comment: I've asked folks to bring these things to Meta, so if you run across something on the site that isn't right, go ahead and ask a question here.  Votes don't count for or against you, so it's a good opportunity to examine more controversial topics.  I know most of you know that, but just for anyone new to SE, etc.